# Git pulled from wrong branch

Tags: git

I have two branches on the server A branch called R2 and a branch called DEV
I inadvertently logged into the wrong server, into the repository and 
performed a 
GIT PULL ORIGIN DEV 
however the repository was on R2.
SO I realized my mistake and then tried to correct my mistake by doing a 
GIT PULL ORIGIN R2
However I end up with a bunch of file names and the error

```
U   view/private_api/ipn.phtml
M   view/reports/menScholarshipForm.pdf
M   view/reports/printProCard.phtml
M   view/reports/printSanction.phtml
M   view/sanctionDetailRoster.html
M   view/sanctionDetailVerify.html
M   view/verifyMembership.phtml
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.
```

I dont mind going in and resetting each file manually, just unsure how to fix my mistake.
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`git pull`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) is just shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`. It looks like you encountered some conflicts at the [`git merge`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) stage.

`git merge --abort` will abort the merge process and try to reconstruct the pre-merge state.

To [reset](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html) `R2` to what is in `origin/R2`:

```
git checkout R2
git fetch origin
git stash # because it's always a good thing to do
git reset --hard origin/R2
```

Comment: [*****@dev app]$ git checkout R2
controller/AddCompetition.php: needs merge
controller/Competition.php: needs merge
controller/EditCompetition.php: needs merge
controller/includes/proSearchWS.php: needs merge

Comment: thanks Johnsyweb - that did the trick, hopefully anyone else javing this problem will see this post and your answer

Comment: Aborting the merge was enough. Thanks.